# troubleshoot: LibreOffice on Debian testing (gnome), insert current date shortcut non-functional

Tags: debian, keyboard-shortcuts, libreoffice-calc, gnome-42

I can't seem to be able to figure this one out. I often want to insert the current date in a libbreoffice calc spreadsheet. But when I press the `ctrl+;` shortcut for this, I seem to switch to a different input mode instead. I can't find the setting to control this.

Different input style looks like a underlined `e` .

Screenshot for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iheQV.jpg

I do wish that this shortcut would insert the current date, as it used to do in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I found the anser. The iBus emoji picker was hijacking the shortcut.

I was able to run `ibus-setup` and from that gui chance the shortcut key.

Relevant bug: https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/2390